# Сomposite number

Tags: number-theory

> a)Find the smallest composite number $n$, such that $$n|\left(2^{n-1}-1\right).$$
>   b)This set is infinite?

**My work so far:**

If $p -$ prime number, then $2^{p-1}\equiv1(\bmod p)$ by Fermat's little theorem

Now $n -$ not prime (composite number).

*I need help here*

Comment: The smallest is 3.

Comment: @Vincent: what is the composite status of $3$?

Comment: sorry, i missed this part

Comment: http://oeis.org/A001567

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you search are the numbers pseudoprime to base $2$. The smallest is $341$. There are infinite many such numbers.

Comment: Wikipedia has [some info on Fermat pseudoprimes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_pseudoprime#Definition) that might help you.

Comment: You mean "the numbers Fermat pseudoprime to base $2$", to be more precise. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoprime#Fermat_pseudoprimes

Comment: How to prove that "The smallest base-2 Fermat pseudoprime is 341"?

Comment: @Roman83 Without a computer ?

Comment: @ Peter: Yes, without a computer

Comment: Have never tried that.

Comment: [That guy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Poulet) did, though. It seems that before the Facebook people used to have ample spare time.